# How to make a node visible before any user interaction

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I took and modified a piece of code which allows me to shoot bullets in every direction. It works perfectly. But it is generating a random bullet in the moment when player touch is ended. I have 6 different bullets and for purposes of my game I need player to see them **before** he will tap the screen. I tried to initialize a bullet in a global function and pass it to didMoveToView. It's not working, bullet is generating once and stays at its place. 
 That is my code for initializing a bullet:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var gameOver = false
let cannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cannon")
let bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode()
var endOfScreenRight = CGFloat()
var endOfScreenLeft = CGFloat()

let bmrArray = ["blBl", "magBl", "rBl"]   
let cgyArray = ["cBl", "gBl", "yBl"]   
let yrmArray = ["yBl", "rBl", "magBl"]   
let bulletArray = ["rBullet","magBullet", "blBullet", "cBullet", "gBullet", "yBullet"]

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
 endOfScreenLeft = (self.size.width / 2) * CGFloat(-1)
 endOfScreenRight = self.size.width / 2

 cannon.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
 self.addChild(cannon)

 cannon.zPosition = 0

 var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
 bulletInCannon.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])
 bulletInCannon.position = cannon.position
 addChild(bulletInCannon)

 bulletInCannon.zPosition = 1000

 runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addCgyLine), 
SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(texture: bulletInCannon.texture)
        bullet.position = cannon.position
        addChild(bullet)

        let offset = location - bullet.position
        let direction = offset.normalized()
        let shootAmount = direction * 1000
        let realDestination = shootAmount + bullet.position

        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(realDestination, duration: 2.0)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionDone]))

        var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
        bulletInCannon.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])
        }
}


func addCgyLine () {
    var cgyBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cyanBox")
    cgyBlock.position = CGPointMake(size.width + cgyBlock.size.width/2, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 60) 
    addChild(cgyBlock)
    var randomCGY = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    cgyBlock.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: cgyArray[randomCGY])
    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -cgyBlock.size.width/2, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 60), duration: 3) 
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    cgyBlock.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionDone]))
    SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
}
```

How can I generate a bullet and only then shoot it? I will be glad to hear any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a bullet in a cannon as a global variable, and then create a new bullet in `touchesEnded` which will be the bullet that actually fires from the cannon.  You set that new bullet's texture to the global bullet's texture.  After firing the action, give the global bullet a new texture.  If you need to have a reload time, then remove the global bullet temporarily, and use a `Boolean` to "lock" the cannon from firing until the time has elapsed.

Here's some code that I used.  If the cannon moves, then make sure to update the position of the global bullet.  The subtraction of `CGPoint` gives me an error, but I'm using Xcode 6.4.

**Edit:  Quicker and easier way by giving the `bulletInCannon` a value**

```
var bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rBullet")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    bulletInCannon.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])
    bulletInCannon.position = cannon.position
    addChild(bulletInCannon)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        // Create bullet that will fire from the cannon
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(texture: bulletInCannon.texture)
        bullet.position = cannon.position
        addChild(bullet)

        let offset = location - bullet.position
        let direction = offset.normalized()
        let shootAmount = direction * 1000
        let realDestination = shootAmount + bullet.position

        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(realDestination, duration: 2.0)
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        bullet.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionDone]))

        // Generate a random texture for the global bullet
        var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
        bulletInCannon.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])
    }
}
```

Comment: Sad news, I still can't see a bullet in cannon before I tap to shoot. Don't really know why, I implemented your code and there weren't any errors

Comment: about error with CGPoints: it's because I use operator overloading and did not include code for it in the question

Comment: Odd.  Make sure that you set the position of the cannon, and add it to the scene before the `bulletInCannon` is created.  You may also want to set the `bulletInCannon.zPosition` to something like 0.5 to make sure that it is above the cannon in the scene.

Comment: Yep, I tried! I don't know why, but it's not working :( I've updated my code with the whole `GameScene`. Maybe I missed something? I can't spot a mistake

Comment: Okay, you are using a `let`, not a `var` for the `bulletInCannon`.  A `let` is a constant, which is why you can't set the texture, position, or anything after the definition.  Change it to `var`, and you will be able to modify the properties.  You may also want to change `cannon` to be a `var` as well so that you can change properties.

Comment: I did, sadly nothing happened. Bullet is created only after the touch. And it's not a matter of zPositions, cause I clearly see how bullet is above the cannon. Something is not letting it to randomly appear in didMoveToView

Comment: Okay, got it working now.  I copied your code into a project, and with a couple changes, it now works.  You need to make sure that `bulletInCannon` is a `var` like so: `var bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode()`  Then, in the `didMoveToView` function, instead of setting the texture, run `bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])`  This is due to Swift seeing that the global variable is created, but nothing is being returned.  You can then create `bulletInCannon` properly in the `didMoveToView` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working perfectly now! So if I will set collision detection to those bullets regarding a node that was randomly chosen I'll need to refer to `bullet` node, right? Something like `bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: rBullet.texture)` and so on for every node in array?

Comment: That should work, as the `bulletInCannon` is just a prop.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by every node in the array, but as long as you set up `bullet` such as `bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bullet.texture)` in order to keep the same texture being used, it should do collision and contact detection.  I will note that in physics, circles are much easier to compute.  Also, if you want the `bullet` to not be affected by gravity, make sure to set `bullet.physicsBody.affectedByGravity` to false.

Comment: I mean, could I set in didBeginContact that for example bullet with texture "rBullet" would collide only with cgyBlock texture "redBox"? They are chosen randomly but I need to specify bullet texture contact with every block texture. Like if bullet is green and it hits green box: score++, but if it hits blueBox: game over

Comment: That would be a different question.  I will point you to the documentation on `SKPhysicsBody` collisions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14).  You may also need to use precise collision detection if the bullet is going really fast.