# How to detect contact regarding sprite texture

Tags: sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have a bullet that should be fired at block. Bullet has 6 different random textures to mimic different bullets. And block has 3 different textures chosen randomly to look like there are 3 different blocks. I want to specify in code that if bullet texture is red, and block texture is red then score should increase, but if bullet is red and block is green it will be the game over. I don't really know how to tell game to do so in didBeginContact.

By now I have this:
In the GameScene & didMoveToView:

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let None      : UInt32 = 0
static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
static let CgyBlock  : UInt32 = 0b1       
static let Bullet    : UInt32 = 0b10
}

bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bullet.texture, size: self.bullet.size)
bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock
bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
bullet.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

In didBeginContact:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
firstBody = contact.bodyA
secondBody = contact.bodyB
} else {
firstBody = contact.bodyB
secondBody = contact.bodyA
}


    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock != 0) &&
        (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Bullet != 0)) 
  //and here I suppose I need to implement somehow something like
 // && (bullet.texture = "redBullet") && (CgyBlock.texture = "greenBlock" || "blackBlock")
 {
   gameOver()        
    }
```

But I know it will not work. I also tried to make a switch statement inside curly brackets and it didn't work either. How to implement that?

**Update:** This is how a block is made:

```
var cgyBlock = SKSpriteNode()

let cgyArray = ["cyanBox", "greenBox", "yellowBox"]

func addCgyLine () {
    cgyBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cyanBox")
    var randomCGY = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    cgyBlock.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: cgyArray[randomCGY])

    cgyBlock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: cgyBlock.texture, size: cgyBlock.size)
    cgyBlock.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    cgyBlock.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock
    cgyBlock.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
    cgyBlock.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None

    cgyBlock.position = CGPointMake(size.width + cgyBlock.size.width/2, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 60) 
    addChild(cgyBlock)

    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -cgyBlock.size.width/2, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 60), duration: 3) 
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    cgyBlock.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionDone]))
    SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
}
```

And then I do runAction in didMoveToView.

**Bullets:**

```
var cannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cannon")
var bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode()
var bullet = SKSpriteNode()

let bulletArray = ["redBullet","magentaBullet", "blueBullet", "cyanBullet", "greenBullet", "yellowBullet"]

//didMoveToView:
 var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
 bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])
 bulletInCannon.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
 addChild(bulletInCannon)

 //touchesEnded:
var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
        bullet = SKSpriteNode(texture: bulletInCannon.texture)
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        bullet.name = bulletArray[randomBullet]
        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bullet.texture, size: self.bullet.size)
        bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        addChild(bullet)
 bulletInCannon.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bulletArray[randomBullet])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ways to go :

1. You can use node's [userData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property.

   ```
   bullet.userData = ["type" : "white"]
   ```

   To access it:

   ```
   println(bullet.userData?["type"])
   ```
2. You can create custom Bullet class which is subclass of SKSpriteNode and create property called "type", and in didBeginContact to access that property.

   ```
   class Bullet: SKSpriteNode {

       var type:String = ""


        init(type:String) {
            self.type = type //later you are accessing this with bulletNode.type
           //This is just an simple example to give you a basic idea  what you can do.
           //In real app you should probably implement some kind of security check to avoid wrong type
           let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: type)

           super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture.size())
       }

       required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
       }
   }
   ```
3. You can use `bullet.name` property as well, and on creation to set it appropriately based on bullet/block colour. Later in didBeginContact you will check `bullet.name` to find out the bullet type. Same goes for blocks.

   ```
   func spawnBulletWithType(type:String) -> SKSpriteNode{

        //set texture based on type
        //you can pass here something like white_bullet

        let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "myAtlas")


        //here, if passed white_bullet string, SpriteKit will search for texture called white_bullet.png
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(texture:atlas.textureNamed(type))


        bullet.name = type // name will be white_bullet, and that is what you will search for in didBeginContact

        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bullet.texture, size: bullet.size)
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        return bullet
   }
   ```

EDIT:

Based on your recent comments you could probably go with this:

```
let bulletArray = ["redBullet","magentaBullet", "blueBullet", "cyanBullet", "greenBullet", "yellowBullet"]

//didMoveToView:
 var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
 let bulletType = bulletArray[randomBullet]
 bulletInCannon.name = bulletType
 bulletInCannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: bulletType )
 bulletInCannon.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
 addChild(bulletInCannon)


//touchesEnded:
var randomBullet = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
        bullet = SKSpriteNode(texture: bulletInCannon.texture)
        bullet.name = bulletInCannon.name
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bullet.texture, size: self.bullet.size)
        bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
        bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock
        bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bullet.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        addChild(bullet)
let bulletType = bulletArray[randomBullet]
 bulletInCannon.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bulletType)
 bulletInCannon.name = bulletType
```

Comment: The third way looks pretty harmless. So, as I understood, I need to make a switch statement for bullet names, regarding its texture right after texture has been chosen. But I still not sure how to declare it in didBeginContact. I tried switch and xcode gave me an error "binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operands 'String' and 'SKTexture?'" I tried this: `switch cgyBlock.texture {
        case "redBlock" :
            cgyBlock.name = "redCgyBlock"
        default: break
        }`

Comment: I can't see exactly  how you create / fire a bullet... But it can be done based on type. So, in the method which create the bullet, pass the type(which is String) as parameter. Switch the type and use it to initialize bullet with appropriate texture, set the type (bullet.name = "type". Those are steps. I can write an example for you if you get stuck.

Comment: It would be really nice, I've never used userData before. Maybe I should put it inside the array where I store those textures? I've updated the question to show how I'm creating a block if it helps. Bullets are created in the same way.

Comment: @Burundanga Third example was related to using name of the node, not userData property ;) I added example on how to use name property. Just access the name in didBeginContact and see what kind of bullet you are dealing with.

Comment: So, in your example you can go with block.name = randomCGY

Comment: Ok, I added `cgyBlock.name = String(randomCGY)` to my method that creates blocks and `bullet.name = String(randomBullet)` to bullet method. But I'm experiencing troubles with accessing it in didBeginContact. I'm trying to do this: `if bullet.name = "redBullet" & cgyBlock.name = "redBox" { score++ }` and I have an error "cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String?'". But I never declared it as an optional.

Comment: @Burundaga Use == operator instead of =. Also, use && instead of &... You need if bullet.name == "redBullet" && cgyBlock.name == "redBox" ...

Comment: Thanks! Errors are gone, but the whole function isn't working, it's not detecting contact. I think that it is bullet to blame because I'm creating it [a little bit tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096800/how-to-make-a-node-visible-before-any-user-interaction). I also set up a `println` instead of `score++` for every possible contact that should print me the type of contact (green bullet - red box) but the console is empty.

Comment: @Burundanga Is it worked before changes? If it is, then just add that check inside your code (where you handle contact) It should work like that.

Comment: Well, I don't know, I haven't tried it before because the whole point is to find a color match between a bullet and a block. I deleted all that `if bullet.name == "redBullet..."` from `if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock != 0)...` and set a `println("Hit")` and it's detecting it. Maybe I shouldn't put those name checks inside `PhysicsCategory` checking method and it is better to declare it somewhere else?

Comment: @Burundanga If contact is properly detected, then I can't see why checking node's name is a problem. Println names of both nodes and see if everything is okay there.

Comment: So, I see a problem. When I wrote `bullet.name = String(randomBullet)` I thought that names would be "redBullet", "greenBullet" and so on. And because of that I did name checks: `if bullet.name == "redBullet"...`But now in didBeginContact, when bullet contacts the block I checked the bullet name: `println("Hit! \(bullet.name)")` and this is what I got in console:  `Hit! Optional("2")`,  `Hit! Optional("0")`. And "redBullet" texture could be every number. Textures are not tied to those numbers. I have no idea why their names are like that.

Comment: Hmm, cgyBlock.name behavior is pretty much the same, but its textures **are** in fact **tied** to numbers. I tried to hit them several times and can say that Optional("0") is a cyan texture and Optional("1") is a green one.

Comment: @Burundanga Just change block.name = cgyArray[randomCGY] instead of just randomCGY.

Comment: It fixed blocks, thanks! But bullets are a little bit different. The problem is: I'm creating them in touchesEnded to simulate shooting. But I needed them to be visible before it so I've been suggested to make a bulletInCannon node that will be visible in didMoveToView. I think because of that their names (as numbers before) are appearing randomly and not matching real textures. Its easy to see my logic in updated question. So now bullet.name and bulletinCannon are using the same things and I think they are accessing randomBullet independently, thats why I have different textures and names.

Comment: I tried so much things and still can't work this out. Bullet names are just really random. I can't make them to be the same as textures! I'm lost here :(

Comment: Okay, I guess I got it. I set bullet name as bullet.name = `String(stringInterpolationSegment: bullet.texture)` and it shows right names in console. But they are not accessible. I get `Optional("Optional(<SKTexture> \'greenBullet\' (35 x 35))") hit Optional("yellowBox")` and there is a green bullet, but I can't access it as "greenBullet"

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define a class for bullets and Blocks
Then you may define a TextureTypes to store your texture types (red,green,…) and set whatever your random method generates into a class variable of this type.
Then you should manage the contact and find out what are the nodes for BodyA and BodyB. after that it is easy to do what ever you like according to the texturetype of your node,

> to clarify the code I have defined Textures as a new Type

```
enum TextureTypes: String {
    case Red,Green 
    var description:String {
        switch self {
        case Red:return “Red"
        case Green:return “Green”
        case Green:return “Blue"
        }
    }
}
```

> Blockclass and BulletClass both hasto inherit from SKNode cause they are a node!

```
class BlockClass:SKNode {
    var NodesTexture : TextureTypes = TextureTypes.Red
}

class BulletClass:SKNode {
    var NodesTexture : TextureTypes = TextureTypes.Red
}
```

> write the following codes into your `didBeginContact` method to detect the TextureType of your Node

```
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bullet) &&    
       (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock)
    {
        Ablock = (BlockClass *) contact.bodyB.node;
        Abullet = (BulletClass *) contact.bodyA.node;
    }
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.CgyBlock) &&    
       (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bullet)
    {
        Ablock = (BlockClass *) contact.bodyA.node;
        Abullet = (BulletClass *) contact.bodyB.node;
        if ( Ablock.NodesTexture = TextureTypes.Red )
        {
            NSLOG(“A Red Block Detected”)

        }
    }
```

Do not forget to define your blocks and bullets of type BlocksClass and BulletClass